# Is Socket wrapper TCP/IP's transport layer?

Tags: sockets

We often hear about this saying:

> Socket is a wrapper around the TCP/IP protocol.

but can make it more clarity? is Socket wrapper TCP/IP's transport layer? or every layer except application layer.

Answer (score 0):

The Socket-interface is more like an API for various Internet and IPC protocols.
It is not really a protocol layer, but in implementation level, it may be used between layers.

For example, a HTTP client may use Socket-API for opening TCP connections to HTTP servers.

In the example the TCP is the transpont layer protocol. Usually TCP uses IP as network layer protocol. And HTTP is the protocol on top of TCP.

The Socket-interface uses term 'socket' for protocol end-points. 
In many systems, a file descriptor type that is created by using `socket()` or `accept()` functions is called a 'socket'.

Comment: I mean, whether Socket API only use the transport layer function, such as tcp, udp, icmp and so on? it do not have api of network layer or network interface layer function right?

Comment: @26334_zeal : May depend on operating system, but in Linux, Socket API offers various ways to use network layer or other lower layers directly without transport layer. For example with options: SOCK_RAW and AF_PACKET.